# User specific Redirect after successful login in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I am working on a sms application .I used **`devise gem`** for authentication and **`carrier wave`** for uploading. My question is after a successful login a user has to redirect to his own page and different users will be having redirecting to different pages.

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and    :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
   attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
   # attr_accessible :title, :body
   has_many :sms
 end
```

**Sm model**

```
class Sm < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :Messages, :Mobile_no, :Nickname, :Templates
  validates_presence_of :Mobile_no
  validates_length_of :Mobile_no, :minimum => 10, :maximum => 10, :allow_blank => true
  validates :Mobile_no, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}
  attr_accessible :sm_id, :name, :image
  belongs_to :sm
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  validate :image_size_validation, :if => "image?"  

  def image_size_validation
    errors[:image] << "should be less than 1MB" if image.size > 1.megabytes
  end

  validates :image, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(xls|xlsx|csv|txt)\z}i,
    message: 'must be a TXT, CSV, XLS, or XLSX'
  }, if: :filename_has_extension?

  def filename_has_extension?
    !(image.to_s =~ /\.[a-z]{1,4}\z/).nil?
  end
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define after_sign_in_path_for method in ApplicationController

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # resource is commonly a User class object
    if resource.admin?
      # redirect somewhere
    else
      # redirect somewhere else
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey For your response.. i have tried with the code but my problem didn solve :(

Comment: I have two models  1. Users  2. sms .. for user model i have used devise gem to create authorized login page .when the user is logged in it ll redirect to sms/new page where i ll type messages to send .. here my aim is when the user for ex 123@yahoo.com logged in he has to view his own messages which he has sent but i am facing when the user 123@yahoo.com logged in he can view all the messages including other user messages ...

Comment: Did you set up associations between models?

Comment: so you can get all user's sms by calling current_user.sms after user signs in

Comment: M unable to meet my expectations ...:( Can you please explain still better

Comment: whenever i use current_user.sms i m getting this error                  NoMethodError in Devise/sessions#new

Showing C:/Sites/smsapps/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #28 raised:

undefined method `sm' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #28):

25: <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %></span>
26: current_user.sms
27: <% end %>
28: <%=  current_user.sm %>
29: 
30: <%= yield %>
31:

Comment: Looks like user is not signed in, could you please post your project to github if it is not private. It will greatly increase productivity of help

Comment: This is not a good idea. Why couldn't you push your code to github?